# How do i add an iterated set of rules to a single one in ARM template for ManagementPolicy

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm-template

I have to add lifecycle rules to my Azure Storage Account. The problem is there are many of them, and their names are provided in an array parameter. However i also have one that is not the same. I know i can use the "copy" function as such:

```
"properties": {
"policy": {
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "rules",
            "count": "[length(parameters('partitions'))]",
            "input": {
                "name": "...",
                "enabled": "true",
                "type": "Lifecycle",
                "definition": {
                    "filters": {
                        "blobTypes": [ "blockBlob" ],
                        "prefixMatch": [
                            "...",
                            "..."
                        ]
                    },
                    "actions": {
                        "baseBlob": {
                            "tierToCool": { "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 10 }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

However this copy function just sort of fills the "rules" property. Is it possible to add another rule to this prefilled set? If so, how do i do that?

Comment: can you show your rule and where to add it?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just copying the "prefixMatch" values in a single rule. This allowed me to define more rules that apply to other containers (that i didn't have to iterate through).